# 401 error when performing GET request w/ axios

Tags: javascript, get, axios, http-status-code-401

I can view my JSON data in my browser but not in my console. I'm not super familiar with axios, but I think the problem is with the url (see snippet below). That, or I'm missing something within `axios.get {`.

Any thoughts?

#### server.js:

```
axios.get("https://handshake.[redacted].com/HandshakeWebServices/Odata/Odata.ashx/HS[redacted]?hsf=@UserName=%27[redacted]%27&$select=PreferredName,Initials,JobTitle,Office", {
    crossDomain: true,
    method: "GET",
    credentials: "include",
    mode: "no-cors",
    headers: {
        "Accept": "application/json; odata=verbose"
    }
})
.then(function(res){
  console.log(res.data);
})
.catch(function(e){
  console.log(e);
})
```

#### console:

```
GET https://handshake.[redacted].com/HandshakeWebServices/Odata/Odata.ashx/HS[redacted]?hsf=@UserName=[redacted]&$select=PreferredName...etc 401 (Unauthorized)

server.js?1d69:18 Error: Request failed with status code 401
    at createError (createError.js?2d83:16)
    at settle (settle.js?467f:18)
    at XMLHttpRequest.handleLoad (xhr.js?b50d:77)
```

Comment: 401 http code means that you are not authorized to request that resource, you probably should send the user credentials diferently? don't know what that site is nor what does it require from you

Comment: `crossDomain: true` is not a property recognised by Axios. (It's a jQuery thing that is almost never useful to modify). Don't use it here.

Comment: You cannot send headers when you use mode no cors

Comment: Given my previous comment and answer, I think the general take-away is that you need to read the documentation for Axios and not the documentation for jQuery or Fetch.

Comment: @Ferrybig — They aren't using mode no-cors … axios doesn't recognise `mode` at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The site is returning a `401` which means you are not authorised to access the URL.

Normally, this means you need to send credentials.

Now, you've said `credentials: "include",` but that's a property recognised by `fetch`, not `axios`. The `axios` equivalent is `withCredentials: true`, so set that instead.

---

You've also said `mode: "no-cors",` which is another property recognised by `fetch`, not `axios`. You don't want it anyway. Sending credentials requires permission via CORS, so by rejecting CORS, reject the possibility to get permission to send the credentials.

Remove that property.